# How do I get pycharm to change the colour of SQL queries in the IDE

Tags: mysql, pycharm, ide, settings

I am currently learning how to use SQL, especially in tandem with python. I use pycharm and the tutorial I am following his IDE changes the colour of queries, and it does not do this in pycharm. Is there a way to change this?

Comparison photos for more clarity.
[PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfqlU.png)
[His IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMaFQ.png)

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.

I already tried asking ChatGPT and google but I can't seem to find an answer specific to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. Turns out the community edition of pycharm does not include SQL language injection. From my current understanding, you have to have the professional edition for SQL commands to be recognised.